# if property1 is empty, then use property2

Tags: c#, winforms, report, expression

```
public string FirstPersonName
    {Get; set; }
public string LocationName
    {Get; set; }

public PropertyEvidenceBL()
{
    if (FirstPersonName==string.empty)
{
 //grab the LocationName in its place. How do I write this.
  return LocationName;  //does not work
}
```

query GetPropertyReport contains all person location info.
business class is PropertyEvidenceBL that has all objects/properties

Comment: What is the error your getting? You are trying to return a value in the constructor. We could use a little more context.

Comment: Also, `get` should be lowercase.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a return statement in the constructor from your posted code. Why?

Try something like this.

Also note you most likely want `string.IsNullOrEmpty` or `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` as your test. `FirstPersonName` in your case is likely ***null*** and not ***empty***. Two very different things.

```
public string FirstPersonName { get; set; }
public string LocationName { get; set; }

public string PersonOrLocationName {
    get {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(FirstPersonName) ? FirstPersonName : LocationName;
    }
}

// From your post this looks like the class constructor...
public PropertyEvidenceBL
{
    // Do something with the name...
    string name = PersonOrLocationName;
}
```

If you're curious about the `? :` syntax, it's shorthand for this:

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(FirstPersonName) {
    return FirstPersonName
}
else {
    return LocationName;
}
```

Comment: Also if using a high enough version of .Net can use `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` if there's a possibility the string could be a space but still counted as empty such as user input.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is separate out your logic checking if the FirstPersonName is empty. Obviously with more code in there handle the return from the CheckFirstName method (not sure what you are doing with it).

```
public PropertyEvidenceBL()
{
    CheckFirstName();
}

private string CheckFirstName()
{   
   if (FirstPersonName == string.empty)
   {
       return LocationName;
   }
   else
   {
      return FirstPersonName
   }        
}
```

Comment: Sorry to get back to you so late, but the the solution from Mike Schwartz worked for me. This was a string of other stuff I needed help with, but thank you finally for helping me resolve the issue.

Comment: If I answered it can you mark it as answered? Thanks